# Zoom automatically returns to its initial zoomlevel

Tags: ios, mapkit

My objective is to make a map in which the user location is shown with annotation and zoom, everything is ok, the location is there with a red annotation and a pretty zoom, for that I have a view which is called **PositionActuelleViewController**, here is my code :

**PositionActuelleViewController.h** :

```
@interface PositionActuelleViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate> {


        MKMapView                   *mapView;
            MKReverseGeocoder           *geoCoder;
        MKPlacemark         *mPlacemark;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D  location;

       }
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**PositionActuelleViewController.m** :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];
        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setDelegate:self];
        [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
        CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    location = newLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = location;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = .005;
    span.longitudeDelta = .005;
    region.span = span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

}
```

**My only problem is that the zoom in is always enabled even if the user zoom out the map, it zoomed in automatically. How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to zoom in once, you can add a boolean ivar called didZoomToUserLocation for example.

In `viewDidLoad`, initialize it to NO before the call to `startUpdatingLocation`:

```
didZoomToUserLocation = NO;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then in `didUpdateToLocation`, change the code like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    location = newLocation.coordinate;

    if (didZoomToUserLocation)
        return;

    didZoomToUserLocation = YES;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = location;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = .005;
    span.longitudeDelta = .005;
    region.span = span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];    
}
```

Note that this will also stop following the user on the map (but the location ivar will still be updated).

If you want to keep following the user but zoom in only the first time, then do this instead:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    location = newLocation.coordinate;

    if (didZoomToUserLocation)
    {
        //just re-center map on user's location without changing zoom...
        [mapView setCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        didZoomToUserLocation = YES;

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = location;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.latitudeDelta = .005;
        span.longitudeDelta = .005;
        region.span = span;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    }        
}
```

Also, in your viewDidLoad, you don't need to call insertSubview on the mapView if it's created in IB.

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for that, iam wondering what you mean in your comment //just re-center map on user's location without changing zoom... ? also, initializing the boolean variables to NO in the viewdidload will prevent the zoom for the the first time, doesn`t it ??

Comment: The "just re-center" means keep the map centered on the user's location but don't change the zoom.  For example if user zoomed the map out (or in), it will keep that zoom level but the map will be centered on the user location.  We named the bool **did**ZoomToUserLocation (actually we mean did-Auto-Zoom-To-User-Location) so we have to init to NO because we haven't done the auto zoom until didUpdateLocation gets called.  If you change the bool name to **needToDo**AutoZoom, then you would init to YES (and reverse your logic in didUpdateToLocation).

Comment: Hi, when i test this on the device, i see the zoom is very high, i mean the zoom in when the view is loaded is very big, what`s the value that i should give to span to let the zoom raisonable ??

Comment: The span values are in degrees.  The [docs for MKCoordinateSpan](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) explain what that translates to in miles/kilometers.  A larger span means a greater area is visible.

Comment: Hi, my problem that i don`t have an iPhone to test the app, but i would ask, for example, which is reasonnable a .002 or .005, in other way, when we talk about visibilty, .002 is# looseness than .005 or the inverse ??

Comment: You can play with the span value in the simulator--it will work.  For example, 0.01 is about 1 km if the latitude is near the equator.  1.00 is about 111 km at the equator. 0.005 is about half km at the equator.  What's "reasonable" depends on your app's requirements.

Comment: Thx a lot for your patience with my questions, but i couldn`t test the zoom at all in the simulator :(

Comment: Ok must be some other issue in your app.  By the way, if you put "ios" or "iphone" tag in your questions in addition to "mapkit", more of the right people will see them.

Comment: if i say that my position is France, what would be the reasonable span value to show my position without over zooming (show me the street, the other streets, a reasonable zoom)? thx

Comment: A value of 0.01 shows a view from the Eiffel Tower to the Boucicaut Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in didUpdateToLocation sets a span of a fixed value. Every time that delegate call is invoked it will set the zoom based on those .005 spans.

If you simply put a breakpoint or log in the function you'll see it generally gets called quite frequently.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, but how would i fix this, i need to set a zoom value when the view is loaded and i need to disable it when the user zoom out ??